# How can I find the list of values in Python that gives the highest R-squared when regressed against another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, scipy-optimize

As the title suggests, I'm trying to use Python as an alternative to Excel solver.

If given a list of values, I want Python to come up with another list of numbers, when taken the natural log of, will result in the highest possible R-squared.

The below is what I've come up with however it doesn't really seem to work. What have I done wrong here? Is there a better library I should be using?

I was expecting something like the numbers below (given the nature of the question there would be multiple possible solutions):

`Best List = [0.258288996, 0.29055507, 0.15215332, 0.395691366, 0.106867761, 0.096624222, 0.114833083, 0.239799601]`

But what I got was:

Best List: [1.         1.         1.         0.99999991 0.99999991 0.99999991  1.         1.        ]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from scipy.optimize import minimize, LinearConstraint

def objective_function(values, df):
    df['Risk Not Optimal'] = values
    df['Log Risk Not Optimal'] = np.log(df['Risk Not Optimal'])
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(df['Returns'], df['Log Risk Not Optimal'])
    r_squared = r_value ** 2
    return -r_squared

data = [0.147490447, 0.15589857, 0.109691117, 0.177958696, 0.084455669, 0.077258315, 0.089590471, 0.142185032]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Returns'])

# Define the bounds for the values of 'Risk Not Optimal'
bounds = [(0, 1)] * len(df)  # Use the length of the DataFrame

# Define the linear constraint for the length
constraint = LinearConstraint(np.ones(len(df)), lb=len(df), ub=len(df))

# Perform optimization to maximize the negative R-squared
result = minimize(objective_function, x0=[1] * len(df), args=(df,), bounds=bounds, constraints=constraint)

best_list = result.x
best_r_squared = -result.fun  # Convert back to positive

print("Best List:", best_list)
print("Best R-squared:", best_r_squared)
```

Comment: I think there's a lot of confusion here, including: you aren't maximizing negative r squared, you're minimizing it.

Answer (score 0):

I just made it optimize over the range `(1,20)` then divided the provided answer to shrink it in your desired range.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from scipy.optimize import minimize, LinearConstraint

data = [0.147490447, 0.15589857, 0.109691117, 0.177958696, 0.084455669, 0.077258315, 0.089590471, 0.142185032]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Returns'])

def objective_function(values):
    df['Risk Not Optimal'] = values
    df['Log Risk Not Optimal'] = np.log(df['Risk Not Optimal'])
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(df['Returns'], df['Log Risk Not Optimal'])
    r_squared = r_value ** 2
    return -r_squared

# Define the bounds for the values of 'Risk Not Optimal'
bounds = [(1, 20)] * len(df)  # Use the length of the DataFrame

# Define the linear constraint for the length
constraint = LinearConstraint(np.ones(len(df)), lb=len(df), ub=len(df))

# Perform optimization to maximize the negative R-squared
result = minimize(objective_function, x0=np.random.uniform(1, 20, len(data)), bounds = bounds)

best_list = np.log(result.x)/np.log(20)
best_r_squared = -result.fun  # Convert back to positive

print("Best List:", best_list)
print("Best R-squared:", best_r_squared)
```

Output

```
Best List: [0.60578837 0.55859341 0.81795237 0.43476225 0.95961056 1.
 0.93079426 0.63557663]
Best R-squared: 0.9999999991137261
```

Comment: you made me realise I needed to wrap the result with np.log! much appreciated

Comment: no actually it was `x0=np.random.uniform(1, 20, len(data)` that made the difference

Answer (score 0):

`R^2 = 1 - SS_res / SS_total` [(wikipedia)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Definitions)

The sum square terms are both sums over functions of individual observations.  So, if we want to find additional observations that make `R^2` higher, we want to keep the value of `SS_res` small, while driving the value of `SS_total` as high as possible.  The residuals are 0 for points that lie on our regression line, so if we regress our original data to find `f`, our MLE regression equation, then additional observations `(x, f(x))` have 0 residual.  Note that adding these observations does not change our regression equation, since any other regression equation has larger squared residuals from both the new observation and the original observations.  So, we now just need to choose some new `x` values.  Our remaining degree of freedom is the `SS_total`, which we can maximize by choosing `x` so that `f(x)` (the y value for that observation) is as far from `\bar{y}` as possible.  For monotone model families, this probably means picking half of our `x` values extremely small (~ -inf) and the other half extremely large (~ inf).

To sum up: Take your original regression equation, and predict on `{-9999, -9999, -9999, 9999, 9999, 9999}`.  The resulting `(x,y)` pairs, when added as observations, should drive `R^2` quickly toward 1.